# Entity Framework: View exclusion without primary key

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using SQL Server where I have designed a view to sum the results of two tables and I want the output to be a single table with the results. My query simplified is something like:

```
SELECT SUM(col1), col2, col3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

This gives me the data I want, but when updating my EDM the view is excluded because "a primary key cannot be inferred".

With a little research I modified the query to spoof an id column to as follows:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS 'ID', SUM(col1), col2, col3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

This kind of query gives me a nice increasing set of ids. However, when I attempt to update my model it still excludes my view because it cannot infer a primary key. How can we use views that aggregate records and connect them with Linq-to-Entities?

Comment: You cannot perform inserts/updates using LINQ if the tables/views you are updating do not have primary keys defined. It needs a way to uniquely identify rows.

Comment: I know it needs a way to uniquely identify rows. Given the task of aggregating data in a table, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: @Jim do you have an id column on one of the source tables? If so you could try `MAX(id) as id`

Comment: @qujck yes, this seems to give me unique ids. However when I update my edmx it still gives me the error "primary key cannot be inferred, table excluded".

Comment: @Jim did you try adding a unique index? `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_table1 ON dbo.Table1(id)`

Comment: Since Table1 already has a primary key (id) it does not allow me to create another clustered index. I think specifying a column as a primary key automatically creates a clustered index.

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) as ID, SUM(col1), col2, col3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col2, col3`

This worked. The entity model was able to infer ID as the primary key. Any drawbacks to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments you can try adding `MAX(id) as id` to the view. Based on your feedback this would become:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) as ID, 
       SUM(col1), 
       col2, 
       col3 
FROM   Table1 
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

Another option is to try creating an index on the view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_view1 ON dbo.View1(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code alter view

```
ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActionDate DESC), -1) AS RowID
```

I use this clause in multi relations view / table query

ROW_NUMBER never give null value because it never seen -1

Answer (score -1):

This is all I needed to add in order to import my view into EF6.

```
select ISNULL(1, 1) keyField
```

Comment: That's the same as `select 1 keyField`, and a non-unique key value for a view is asking for trouble in EF6.

Comment: Hi GERT. If the view is only used for read operations, what trouble might it be asking for in EF6?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17188625/861716).