# Linq To entites query returns wrong data(different than Management Studio Query)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

like the title suggests my problem is that I have a query/Stored Procedure that selects a data from a view and its working just fine at the management studio, the problem is when I try to call this data from my application( using linq to entites) I get wrong data(wrong as in a single row is repeated 10 times when the query should return 5 different rows/records)
Here is my management studio Query :

```
select * from dbo.v_RouteCardDetails_SizeInfo
where  Trans_TransactionHeader = 0
AND Direction = 0
AND RoutGroupID = 1
AND Degree = '1st'
```

### **Result Returned:**

```
Size    SizeQuantity    Trans_TransactionHeader RoutGroupID Direction   Degree

XS  10  0   1   0   1st
S   2   0   1   0   1st
M   0   0   1   0   1st
L   5   0   1   0   1st
XXL 2   0   1   0   1st
```

---

and here is my Linq Query:

```
    (from x in context.v_RouteCardDetails_SizeInfo
                            where  x.Trans_TransactionHeader == 0
                                && x.Direction == 0
                                && x.RoutGroupID == 1
                                && x.Degree.ToLower() == "1st"
                        select x).ToList<_Model.v_RouteCardDetails_SizeInfo>();
```

And the result returned is :

```
Size    SizeQuantity    Trans_TransactionHeader RoutGroupID Direction   Degree

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st

XS  10  0   1   0   1st
```

for 2 days I've been trying to fix this, will appreciate your help
Thanks

Comment: What does sql profiler tell you the EF query is? Alternatively you could use EF Prof to see the actual executed sql coming out of EF. Without that this will be tricky to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undoubtedly the fields that Entity Framework has guessed as primary key of the view are not unique in the view. Try to add fields to the PK in the edmx designer (or code-first mapping) until you've really got a unique combination.

EF just materializes identical rows for each identical key value it finds in the result set from the SQL query.

Comment: I have run into this problem a few times, and this has always been the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not possible to have sme enviroment as your I suggest you do following things:

1. Check in debbuger what exactly is in list. The printed result suggest that you somehow display data returned form database and in this code could be an error.
2. Preview LINQ query. You can use LinqPad for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Garath, I did that and every thing was fine, the problem was Like Gert suggested, and also Thanks for hinting about LinqPad, it proved useful in something else I needed :)

Comment: On SO you don't need to thanks. Just vote up answer if it is useful