# Visual Studio EF database Views error when compiling

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

In my sql table, I am not able to set the primary key for views.  When I try to compile my project, I always get he error.  Is there a way to set the primary key in sql server, or
in Visual Studio to make this error go away?

Warning 2   Error 6002: The table/view 'db.dbo.View_Customer_Active' does not have a        primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.    C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Proj1\Proj1\Models\DB.edmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, but just a warning that tells you that you cannot update and delete items from the view. Views without primary keys is kind of frequently asked question in the context of Entity Framework:

[Entity Framework: View exclusion without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176014/entity-framework-view-exclusion-without-primary-key) or 
[Entity Framework and SQL Server View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view)